# display message a week before and a week after a set date

Tags: php, date

I am trying to echo 'Hello World' a week before and a week after in all the days leading up to/after and including December 25th every year (using this for a logo changer). Unfortunately I am stuck on the logic with the +/- 1 week part and Im not sure what to do, thus far I have it working if the date is Dec 25th.

```
<?php

$xmas = date('Y').'-12-25';

$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));

if ($today == date('Y-m-d', strtotime($xmas))) {
    echo 'hello world!';
}

?>
```

So basically the 25th is a centerpoint with a fixed one week interval both after and prior, where this should display the message.

Comment: is u need to display message from date 14-20 and 28-3 jan 2015

Comment: Examples: `$date = date("Y-m-d");// current date` then `$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");` and `$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " -1 week");` that gives you +1 week and -1 week.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yea but having problems with forming that into a logical expression

Comment: show us what u tried

Comment: Try something like 
`$xmas = date('Y').'-12-25';

$oneweek = strtotime('+1 week');

 if ($xmas < date('Y-m-d', strtotime($oneweek))) {

    echo 'hello world!';
}`

Comment: A week before/after on 25th December is always the same, why would you need to calculate that? What is wrong with if statement like this: `if (date('Y-12-19') <= date('Y-12-25') && date('Y-12-25') <= date('Y-12-31')) { ... }` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$date = date('Y').'-12-25';

$today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

$dateMin = strtotime($date . " -1 week");
$dateMax = strtotime($date . " +1 week");

echo $dateMin . '<br>' . $dateMax . '<br>' . $today;

if (($today >= $dateMin) && ($today <= $dateMax)) {

    echo 'date is in range';

}

?>
```

Comment: I take it this is your solution, yes?